# Create map of keys to specific allowed values

Tags: go, enums, hashmap

I have an enum which contains the names of some keys for a message that I am sending to an API.

```
type ApiFieldNames int
const (
 KeyName1 ApiFieldNames = 999
 KeyName2 ApiFieldNames = 63
 ...
)
```

When I construct the message to send to the API, only certain values are allowed per Field.

I want to make sure that when constructing the message body, only allowed values are used, sometimes the field may have one value that can be used, other times the value can be a few different values or can be any integer/string (username field or timestamp, for example) only.

Right Now I am just using a map, which I just use to lookup the value which is being used to verify that it is valid.

```
var MesageKeyValPairs = map[ApiFieldNames][]string{
  KeyName1: []string{"0", "A", "2"},
  KeyName2: []string{"Y"},
  UserNameKey: []string{},
  TimestampKey: []string{},
}

...


if len(MessageKeyValPairs[currentKey]) > 0 && !(contains(currentVal, MesageKeyValPairs[currentKey])){
 //invalid, handle
}
//continue checking pairs
```

Is there a better way to do this in golang?

Comment: You should use a map instead of the slice, so the `contains()` operation is just a map lookup.

Comment: And definately create a helper function `valid(key ApiFieldNames, value string) bool` to not repeat the whole check every time, just call this `valid()` function, like `if !valid(currentKey, currentVal) {}`